# Can I use express to render/redirect to the mobile version of my site more easily?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

So right now I just have a module that checks the user agent and returns either 'mobile' or 'desktop' which I then use to choose the right jade file to render. This is already pretty messy and it's only getting worse as I add more pages. Is there a way to streamline this process with express?

basically my setup goes like this:

```
function renderPage(req, res){
  if (user agent is mobile){
    jadeVar = mobile
  else{ 
    jadeVar = desktop

  res.render(jadeVar)
```

I have one of these in every function that renders a page.

Comment: Some example of your current setup would help.  I would think most of your responsive design needs can be met by CSS media queries, or possibly swapping out your main layout based on the display type.  But it sounds like you're making multiple copies of every page?

Comment: Checkout the following: [express-device: Browser detection library, built on top of express](https://npmjs.org/package/express-device)

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think having the stylesheet take care of resizing content is the way to go. But, if you want to use the user agent to define a route for you, take a look at this quick tutorial. http://www.hacksparrow.com/mobile-web-development-in-express-js-node-js.html